# Executing SELECT statement through a dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, code-injection

For academical purposes, I'm testing sqlinjection in a simple form page like that:

```
<form method="GET">
   <select name="animalFamily" onchange="submit()">
     <option value='0'> Mammals </option>
     <option value='1'> Reptiles </option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Once submitted, the server performs a query to the database to retrieve all the animals of the selected family and presents them as well in a html dropdown menu, for example:

```
   <select name="mammals">
     <option> Dog </option>
     <option> Cat </option>
   </select>
```

I know that even through an html form which has just dropdown menus sql injection attacks can be performed, for example, provided I know a name of a table, instead of submitting:

```
http://foobar.com/animals/?animalFamily=0
```

I could submit the following URL in order to delete a table named *vegetables*:

```
 http://foobar.com/animals/?animalFamily=0'%3Bdrop+table+vegetables%3B+--
```

But what if I just want to send SELECT sentences and get their results? 
I'm really asked to get the contents of the column *name* of the table *vegetables*. Something like that:

```
http://foobar.com/animals/?animalFamily=0'%3B+select+name+from+vegetables%3B--
```

Would there be any way to make the results of the SELECT visible in the resulting page?

Comment: This entirely depends on the server side code. Please add that to your question (you do have access to this code, for your academic research right?)

Comment: Hi Steve, no, I don't have access to the code, but I guess it's as simple as it can be: the php retrieves the value of the animalFamily parameter selected, and fills the new dropbox iterating through the values of the column which contains the animals.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Hi, no, unfortunately I can't share the url, but I've updated the question to be more specific: I know that the table vegetables has a column "name", that's the info I must retrive. I've been thinking about using an UNION clause, but it doesn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong: http://foobar.com/?animalFamily=0%22+union+select+name+from+vegetables%3B--